# Playing a sound on a scrollview button - Android

Tags: android

I currently have an app whereby there is a scrollview a-z at the bottom of one of the .xml files, when pressing each letter, a different image appears to correspond to that letter.

I have added 2 extra buttons above the scroll view btn_letter & btn_word, and would like to have them make a sound relating to the particular letter on the scrollview, for example;

If user presses 'B' on scrollview, a picture relating to B appears - this works currently.
However, I would also like it so the 2 extra buttons I created will play a sound on press relating to B so if user presses btn_letter , sound b1.mp3 would play, if they press btn_word, sound b2.mp3 would play, if the selected scrollview was on C, then it would be c1.mp3 and c2.mp3 for the button and so on.

The code for the first 2 letters is here;

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_a"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:onClick="setImage"
    android:tag="1"
    android:text="A"
    android:textColor="#000000" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_b"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:onClick="setImage"
    android:tag="2"
    android:text="B"
    android:textColor="#000000" />
```

For the button themselves, at the moment, just on a switch inside the .java file;

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
         switch (v.getId()){

             case R.id.btn_word:
                       // play a word sound
                        break;

             case R.id.btn_letter:
                       // play a letter sound
                        break;
       }    
  }
```

Comment: save scrollposition and scrolled letter. then choose appropriate mp3

Comment: Hi Divyesh could you elaborate a little I am still very new to Android, trying to work it out from my Xcode project I made of the same app.

Comment: you have to make listview for this. so your function work very easy way

Comment: Thanks, although that answer is hard for me to understand, can I not use tags instead?